# .save() is not a function (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

So, I'm not 100% why this isn't working as intended. I have an Edit Profile React component (I'm learning how to build a SSR-based application currently, using the MERN stack) - but when I submit the edit, I get an error that **"user.save is not a function** - Code:

From the routes:

```
    router.route('/api/users/:userId')
    .get(authCtrl.requireSignin, userCtrl.read)
    .put(authCtrl.requireSignin, authCtrl.hasAuthorization, userCtrl.update)
    .delete(authCtrl.requireSignin, authCtrl.hasAuthorization, userCtrl.remove)
```

The API Helper:

```
const update = async (params, credentials, user) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('/api/users/' + params.userId, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
      },
      body: user
    })
    return await response.json()
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

And lastly, the actual controller, that handles all the logic behind the update: (This function sanitizes the password information before passing it back to the client, hence the undefineds)

```
const update = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.keepExtensions = true
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Photo could not be uploaded"
      })
    }
    let user = req.profile
    user = extend(user, fields)
    user.updated = Date.now()
    if(files.photo){
      user.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path)
      user.photo.contentType = files.photo.type
    }
    try {
      await user.save()
      user.hashed_password = undefined
      user.salt = undefined
      res.json(user)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

This isn't a production level application, just for me learning how to do this from scratch (without CRA, and all contained in one project using SSR)

EDIT: After some digging, console.logs and console.dirs, I discovered that the updates passed from the component aren't even being passed to the controller. The stale data (from the database) are logging, but req.profile is completely empty. I may re-visit this code completely and make some major changes to it.. All part of learning, right?

Here are the auth methods that were requested (I'm using Session Storage for now, but that may change to localStorage):

```
import User from '../models/user.model'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt'
import config from './../../config/config'

const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({error: "User not found"})
    }
    if (!user.authenticate(req.body.password)) {
      return res.status(401).send({error: "Email and Password do not match"})
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, config.jwtSecret)

    res.cookie('t', token, {expire: new Date() + 9999})

    return res.json({
      token,
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({error: "Could not sign in"})
  }
}

const signout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('t')
  return res.status(200).json({message: "Signed out"})
}

const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  algorithms: ['sha1', 'RS256', 'HS256'],
  userProperty: 'auth'
})

const hasAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorized = req.profile && req.auth
  && req.profile._id == req.auth._id
  if (!(authorized)) {
    return res.status(403).json ({error: "User is not authorized"})
  }
  next()
}


export default {
  signin,
  signout,
  requireSignin,
  hasAuthorization
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for these 2 methods?
`authCtrl.requireSignin` and `authCtrl.hasAuthorization`

Answer (score 0):

Possible places where you could have a mistake: (code is not shown)

If your req.profile isn't a mongoose object, this won't work

```
let user = req.profile
```

From your other posts, I think you're probably getting req.profile from your jwt. That means this is not a mongoose object. What you'll need to do is either:

- As you mentioned, use `findByIdAndUpdate` passing the `id` and the object to be updated. Note that if you have a mongoose middleware for `save` it won't run here
- Do a `user = await User.findById(id)`, update the user as you see fit, then use `user.save`. This gives you a bit more control over it, but runs 2 operations.

Comment: req.profile is coming from a form submission on the client, and then it should be sent to the Database via a PUT method (updating the profile). I posted the submit action in a separate answer.. Still trying to wrap my brain around how SO works from an authors perspective. Usually I just look things up lol

Comment: After some further research, would findByIdAndUpdate be more appropriate than a simple PUT ?

Comment: @MikePhelps you're mixing things up. `PUT` and `findByIdAndUpdate` are not mutually exclusive, they are very different things that can/should be used together. Post the code where you set `req.profile`. Each question should have the code relevant to it on it

Comment: @MikePhelps I've updated my answer, it should be what you need

Comment: I think I may have found the culprit.. more logging and such, and it turns out that FormData isn't being populated on my submit action, so req.body is being passed as empty, so it's not doing anything with the data at the moment.. once I get that sorted out I think I can get the save to work, as I'm able to get req.params, and req,params.userId, so findById() returns the right record..

Comment: Since the above is an unrelated issue, I'm going to just start a new thread on that issue, as it has nothing to do (so far) with the save() is not a function..

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.. My issue was apparently with the form not passing the request body properly to the API, which was caused by a faulty install of a dependency. Once I got that solved, the rest fell into place, and I can now do what I need to do with ease..

Thank you all who attempted to troubleshoot this with me.